# Error al enviar por segunda vez datos post desde una activity

Tags: php, android, android-studio, json

Mi problema es el siguiente: Es una app de mensajeria instantanea, la parte siguiente es como se envia un mensaje a la url correspondiente mediante JSON a PHP y a mi base de datos por método POST.

Se envia correctamente la primera vez ,se almacenan los datos en la base de datos y todo ok, pero ahi mismo trato de enviar por segunda vez un mensaje sale `Se envio mensaje` pero no se envia nada ni cerrando sesion y volviendo ingresar, se manda nuevamente si entro al equipo elimino datos y cache de la aplicacion vuelvo entrar a la aplicacion mando un mensaje y se envia correctamente pero igual sigue si intento mandar una segunda vez (No manda error ni nada pero no se manda los datos hasta eliminar cache de la aplicación del celular).

Por favor si conocen el problema como lo solucionaron.

```
private void sendMessage(String emisor, final String receptor, String mensaje, final String tipo_mensaje){

        SolicitudesJson s = new SolicitudesJson() {
            @Override
            public void solicitudCompletada(JSONObject j) {
                Toast.makeText(MessageActivity.this, "Se envio mensaje", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void solicitudErronea() {
                Toast.makeText(MessageActivity.this, "se envio mensaje ,error servidor", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        };
        HashMap<String,String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
        hashMap.put("id_emisor", emisor);
        hashMap.put("id_receptor", receptor);
        hashMap.put("mensaje", mensaje);
        hashMap.put("mensaje_direccion", "enviado");
        hashMap.put("tipo_mensaje",tipo_mensaje);
        s.solicitudJsonPOST(MessageActivity.this,SolicitudesJson.URL_USUARIO_ENVIAR_MENSAJE,hashMap);
    }

El JSONPOST se conecta a la clase abstracta siguiente........................
public abstract class SolicitudesJson {

    public abstract void solicitudCompletada(JSONObject j);
    public abstract void solicitudErronea();
    public SolicitudesJson(){}

    public void solicitudJsonGET(Context c, String URL){
        JsonObjectRequest solicitud = new JsonObjectRequest(URL,null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject datos) {
                solicitudCompletada(datos);
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                solicitudErronea();
            }
        });
        VolleyRP.addToQueue(solicitud,VolleyRP.getInstance(c).getRequestQueue(),c,VolleyRP.getInstance(c));
    }
    public void solicitudJsonPOST(final Context c, String URL, HashMap h){
        JsonObjectRequest solicitud = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,URL,new JSONObject(h), new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject datos) {
                solicitudCompletada(datos);
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                solicitudErronea();
            }
        });
        VolleyRP.addToQueue(solicitud,VolleyRP.getInstance(c).getRequestQueue(),c,VolleyRP.getInstance(c));
    }
}
VolleyRP que se menciona es de la siguiente clase tambien usada respectivamente.
public class VolleyRP {

    private static VolleyRP mVolleyRP = null;
    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;

    private VolleyRP(Context context) {
        mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
    }

    public static VolleyRP getInstance(Context context) {
        if (mVolleyRP == null) {
            mVolleyRP = new VolleyRP(context);
        }
        return mVolleyRP;
    }

    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        return mRequestQueue;
    }

    public static void addToQueue(Request request, RequestQueue fRequestQueue, Context context, VolleyRP volley) {
        if (request != null) {
            request.setTag(context);
            if (fRequestQueue == null)
                fRequestQueue = volley.getRequestQueue();
            request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                    60000, 3, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT
            ));
            fRequestQueue.add(request);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Que realiza solicitudJsonPOST() ?

Comment: Ahi complete lo que realiza el JsonPOST.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba eliminando el uso de cache `mRequestQueue.setShouldCache(false)`

Comment: Fue correcto ,con ello se solucionaba el problema pero estaba deshabilitado la funcion setShouldCache(false) en forma que habia era mRequestQueue.getCache().clear();